# UIImageView masks and bottom alignment

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on an app that has TableViewCells with varying heights. I am placing a UIImageView into them and each will use the same size image (the same size of the largest cell), however I need to mask the excess in the smaller cells (keeping the bottom, not the top).

To be more specific, I have 3 different cell heights, 112, 104 and 88. The images will all be 112 tall and I want the images to have the tops cut off on the smaller cells. Im pretty sure the answer lies within the bounds, frame and center attributes of a UIImageView, but I cant figure out exactly what I should be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set the frame of your image view such that the bottom of the image view is aligned with the bottom of your cell.

You will also need to ensure the contentview of you cell is clipping content to its bounds (setClipToBounds to yes).

If I had to do this I would subclass the UITabelViewCell class and implement the layoutSubviews method. In your implementation don't forget to call super first so the content view has the right size (also if you go in editing mode). Then use the content view bounds and place your content accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the image view to the cell, it should automatically cut off the top part, as long as you have the UIImageView bottom positioned within the frame, it should be what you wanted.